# multiple loop and printing something else if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to create some sort of schedule calendar.
What I am doing first is creating a list, where I simply add dictionary data, with the following output:

**week_day** : to show the week of the current data field
**module_id** : to show where the current data field is linked to(because each day has X modules)
**day** : the current day it is linked to
**course** : just metadata to the following day, in this case a course.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

list = []

d1 = {'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 1, 'day' :  8, 'course' : 'Course1'}
d2 = {'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 2, 'day' :  8, 'course' : 'Course2'}
d3 = {'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 1, 'day' :  9, 'course' : 'Course3'}
d4 = {'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 3, 'day' : 10, 'course' : 'Course4'}
d5 = {'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 2, 'day' : 11, 'course' : 'Course5'}
d6 = {'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 1, 'day' : 12, 'course' : 'Course6'}
d7 = {'week_day': 51, 'module_id': 1, 'day' : 15, 'course' : 'Course7'}
d8 = {'week_day': 51, 'module_id': 1, 'day' : 16, 'course' : 'Course8'}

list.append(d1)
list.append(d2)
list.append(d3)
list.append(d4)
list.append(d5)
list.append(d6)
list.append(d7)
list.append(d8)
```

as a test, I am just giving the day to have 4 modules, with the ID numbers (int)

```
module = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

my method to get the current days of the selected week and year. I am using the first 5 days.

```
def get_week_days(year, week):
    """
    will get all the '5 working days' in the week, it will print the week name.
    based on the corresponding year and weeknumber
    """
    d = date(year,1,1)
    d = d - timedelta(d.weekday())
    dlt = timedelta(days = (week-1)*7)
    start_date = d + dlt
    end_date = d + dlt + timedelta(days=4)
    list = []
    while True:
        dict = {
        'dayname' : '{:%A}'.format(start_date),
        'date'    : int('{:%d}'.format(start_date))
        }
        list.append((dict))
        start_date = start_date + timedelta(days=1)
        if start_date > end_date:
            break
    return list
```

Now here comes my problem, I can get the data from the following weeks and year. But I am not sure how to implement the modules and print empty data if the module to the linked day doesn't have data.

```
for x in get_week_days(2014, 50):
    for y in list:
        if x['date'] == y['day']:
            print(y['course'])
```

### what it should print instead

so it has to print all the courses of the 5 weekdays
it should print day 1 like this (day 8 in this case)

{'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 1, 'day' :  8, 'course' : 'Course1'}
{'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 2, 'day' :  8, 'course' : 'Course2'}
'empty'
'empty'

*and then continue to day 2 (day 9 in this case)*

{'week_day': 50, 'module_id': 1, 'day' :  9, 'course' : 'Course3'}
'empty'
'empty'
'empty'

and so on, but as you see it should also print with the corresponding modules, and if there is no course
with the module id, it should print an empty string or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understood your problem, but here is what seems to be a quick fix.

```
for x in get_week_days(2014, 50):
    x_mod = [False for _ in module]
    for y in list:
        if x['date'] == y['day']:
            x_mod[y['module_id']-1] = y
    for my_module in x_mod:
        print(my_module if my_module else 'empty')
```

However, it would probably be wise to change your algorithm so that it would become more scalable. For instance, if the events are sorted by date as in your example, you don't need to go over every entry this often, a single traversal should be enough.

(By the way, avoid using list as a variable name.)

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot sir, I didn't knew the `[False for _ in module]`, thanks for sharing the little trick!

Comment: I guess you could also use `[0]*len(module)` if you aim for shorter

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks! Always a fan of learning new tricks and how to enhance the code!